# Enterprise Architect Forward Engineering (UML Model to C++ )

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I want to include some of standard c++ headers as a part of code generation.  In Class Diagram, what UML element can i use to represent (for example: iostream) such a dependency in UML model, so that it wont generate .h or .cpp for those headers in code generation.

Assume Project contains class1(name it as Trace class) which is derived from iostream. Upon code generation, i am expecting only Trace.cpp and Trace.h

Currently i am using class element for those headers and connecting Trace class with Generalization relation, but EA generating iostream.h file as well as it is including those headers within " " instead of < >

Answer (score 0):

If you move your `iostream` class to a different package (one outside teh hierarchy you generate from) EA won't generate code for it.

Comment: After moving to different hierarchy, EA is not generating file for iostream, but it is not including iostream in Trace.h within '<' and '>'. I have referred C++ code generation script (File) and tried to include it inside <> , but couldn't find a way. Is there any .eap/.xmi project which contains such c++ headers? If so, anybody just import and use it in their project.